# Use same collation for string comparison in migration script

Tags: mysql, liquibase, collation

I have an application, which is running on different databases.

For migration I use Liquibase scripts.

Lately I had a script which migrated a `varchar` column (let's name it `exampleName`) from a really big table `ExampleTable` to its own table `NameTable` and replaced it with the reference `exampleName_id`:

```
<createTable tableName="NameTable">
    <column name="id" type="${type.bigint}" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
        <constraints nullable="false" />
    </column>
</createTable>

<addUniqueConstraint tableName="NameTable" constraintName="unique_name" columnNames="name" />

<sql>INSERT INTO NameTable (name) SELECT DISTINCT exampleName FROM ExampleTable</sql>

<addColumn tableName="ExampleTable">
    <column name="exampleName_id" type="${type.bigint}"
            valueComputed="(SELECT n.id FROM NameTable n WHERE n.name = ExampleTable.exampleName)" />
</addColumn>

<addNotNullConstraint tableName="ExampleTable" columnName="exampleName_id" columnDataType="${type.bigint}" />

<addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="FK_ExampleTable_exampleName_id" 
                         baseTableName="ExampleTable" baseColumnNames="exampleName_id"
                         referencedTableName="NameTable" referencedColumnNames="id" />

<dropColumn tableName="ExampleTable" columnName="exampleName" />
```

A local test was working fine on different databases, even on MySQL.

On one of the installation machines, running on MySql, I get the following error when migrating:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
[Failed SQL: (1267) UPDATE myschema.ExampleTable SET exampleName_id = (SELECT n.id FROM NameTable n WHERE n.name = ExampleTable.exampleName)]
```

Apparently on this machine the new column `NameTable.name` has a different collation than the existing column `ExampleTable.exampleName`. I don't know how it happened, that the default collation is different from the existing one, I'd guess it has something to do with a recent upgrade to a newer MySQL version.

The error is well documented and I know that there are different approaches to fix it, for example I could use an explicit collation for comparison:

```
<addColumn tableName="ExampleTable">
    <column name="exampleName_id" type="${type.bigint}"
            valueComputed="(SELECT n.id FROM NameTable n WHERE n.name = ExampleTable.exampleName COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci)" />
</addColumn>
```

But this has some drawbacks:

- I don't know the collation of the column on the different machines in advance. So maybe it prevents using the existing index on that really big table, if the collation differs.
- This is not SQL dialect independent, I would need to write one statement for MySQL and one for the other dialects (and that for each varchar comparison).

Is there a MySQL or Liquibase option to use the collation of the existing column for the new column? Or an option to automatically use the collation of the existing index when comparing, without haven to specify one in each comparison?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved.  Also `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` is shown above, in the form of a Liquibase command. The application is running on different MySQL instances, running on different MySQL versions (and other database types). So even `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES ...` or a schema dump would slightly differ on these machines. I've already fixed the problem for the specific machine and now I'm looking for an environment independent way - one of the reasons for using Liquibase - to ensure, that it won't happen again on other machines.